# Any tools for testing ad hoc JPQL queries outside of an application?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, toplink

I'm working on a project which uses JPA for persistence, and I'm trying to find the cleanest and most efficient means for testing JPQL queries.  I am more accustomed to the Hibernate world... in which you can test HQL on an ad hoc basis outside the application, using Hibernate Tools and its Hibernate Console.  I believe that tool also supports JPQL if you use Hibernate as the JPA provider, but unfortunately in this case I'm on GlassFish and using TopLink.

Are there any rough equivalents to the Hibernate Console l out there (or in development) in the general JPA world?  If not, what is your typical practice for tinkering around with JPQL queries during development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to Execute JPQL Queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615494/tool-to-execute-jpql-queries)

Comment: Possibly (I can't believe that didn't turn up in my search results).  However, it's been a full year since that one... and one would think that SOMETHING new had come along since then, as hard as JPA 2 is being pushed.  Eclipse Dali is still stagnant on the JPQL Editor front, as is the vaporware one that was supposed to be in NetBeans 7 by now.  JQT was an interesting find, but I haven't had a positive experience with it thus far.  I may have to give the "accept" to duffymo for pointing out the new IntelliJ, but it does suck that the only good option is commercial.  I miss Hibernate.  :)

Comment: The latest answers are from Jul 2010, that's more important than the age of the question IMO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How 'bout IntelliJ, the best IDE around?

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/jpa/

Comment: I guess I'll give the points to this answer since IntelliJ wasn't covered in that older "duplicate" question.  It seems the plugins for Eclipse and NetBeans are still vaporware after a full year, and nothing else really solid has come along.  Still, it's disappointing that the only solid option is a commercial proprietary one.  Few companies will drop $600 per seat on IntellJ... when virtually all Java developers are fluent in Eclipse or NetBeans, and a rare shortcoming like this can be worked around by manually writing a test class.  Oh well.

Comment: " Few companies will drop $600 per seat on IntellJ" - at your hourly rate, I can assume you that IntelliJ will more than pay for itself in a very short period of time.  An individual seat costs far less.  I buy a personal license every year and use that wherever I go.